# Can only concatenate str

Tags: python-3.x

I ran a command through python like:

```py
>>> "nmap" + options +" "+ IP
```

And it gives me the error that *it can only come a string and not a list*. Do I have any lists here?

Comment: A little bit more context would be helpful. Both `options` and `IP` could be anything, perhaps a list. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure all of the concatenated variables are strings, try this:

```py
Command = "nmap" + str(options) +" "+ str(IP)
```

Answer (score -1):

If it says you are concatenating a list, find the variable which is the list (I will assume `options` in this case) and use the str.join method:

```
Command = "nmap" + "".join(options) +" "+ IP
```

If options contains something which is not a string, you can convert the list and then join it:

```
Command = "nmap" + "".join([str(i) for i in options]) +" "+ IP
```